# Configuring Mailhog on Mac

Tags: mailhog

I'm trying to configure mailhog on mac. I have it installed (homebrew) and ran maillog.

My console shows:

mailhog
2022/01/19 11:21:42 Using in-memory storage
2022/01/19 11:21:42 [SMTP] Binding to address: 0.0.0.0:1025
[HTTP] Binding to address: 0.0.0.0:8025
2022/01/19 11:21:42 Serving under http://0.0.0.0:8025/
Creating API v1 with WebPath:
Creating API v2 with WebPath:
[APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
[APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events

Then, I try to trigger an email send, and the console shows:

> [APIv2] GET /api/v2/jim [APIv2] GET /api/v2/messages [APIv2] GET
> /api/v2/websocket [APIv2] GET /api/v2/messages [APIv2] GET
> /api/v2/messages 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] Starting
> session 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: INVALID]
> Started session, switching to ESTABLISH state 2022/01/19 11:24:04
> [SMTP [::1]:60932] Sent 35 bytes: '220 mailhog.example ESMTP
> MailHog\r\n' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60933] Starting session
> 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60933] [PROTO: INVALID] Started
> session, switching to ESTABLISH state 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP
> [::1]:60933] Sent 35 bytes: '220 mailhog.example ESMTP MailHog\r\n'
> 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] Received 676 bytes: 'GET /
> HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:1025\r\nConnection:
> keep-alive\r\nsec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google
> Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"\r\nsec-ch-ua-mobile:
> ?0\r\nsec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests:
> 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71
> Safari/537.36\r\nAccept:
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nSec-Fetch-Site:
> none\r\nSec-Fetch-Mode: navigate\r\nSec-Fetch-User:
> ?1\r\nSec-Fetch-Dest: document\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate,
> br\r\nAccept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8\r\n\r\n' 2022/01/19
> 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Processing line: GET /
> HTTP/1.1 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In
> state 1, got command 'GET', args '/ HTTP/1.1' 2022/01/19 11:24:04
> [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In ESTABLISH state 2022/01/19
> 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Got unknown command for
> ESTABLISH state: 'GET' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] Sent 26
> bytes: '500 Unrecognised command\r\n' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP
> [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Processing line: Host: localhost:1025
> 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In state 1,
> got command 'HOST:', args 'localhost:1025' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP
> [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In ESTABLISH state 2022/01/19 11:24:04
> [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Got unknown command for
> ESTABLISH state: 'HOST:' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] Sent
> 26 bytes: '500 Unrecognised command\r\n' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP
> [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Processing line: Connection:
> keep-alive 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH]
> In state 1, got command 'CONNECTION:', args 'keep-alive' 2022/01/19
> 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In ESTABLISH state
> 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Got unknown
> command for ESTABLISH state: 'CONNECTION:' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP
> [::1]:60932] Sent 26 bytes: '500 Unrecognised command\r\n' 2022/01/19
> 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Processing line:
> sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97",
> "Chromium";v="97" 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO:
> ESTABLISH] In state 1, got command 'SEC-CH-UA:', args '" Not;A
> Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"' 2022/01/19
> 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In ESTABLISH state
> 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Got unknown
> command for ESTABLISH state: 'SEC-CH-UA:' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP
> [::1]:60932] Sent 26 bytes: '500 Unrecognised command\r\n' 2022/01/19
> 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Processing line:
> sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO:
> ESTABLISH] In state 1, got command 'SEC-CH-UA-MOBILE:', args '?0'
> 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In ESTABLISH
> state 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Got
> unknown command for ESTABLISH state: 'SEC-CH-UA-MOBILE:' 2022/01/19
> 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] Sent 26 bytes: '500 Unrecognised
> command\r\n' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH]
> Processing line: sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS" 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP
> [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In state 1, got command
> 'SEC-CH-UA-PLATFORM:', args '"macOS"' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP
> [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In ESTABLISH state 2022/01/19 11:24:04
> [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Got unknown command for
> ESTABLISH state: 'SEC-CH-UA-PLATFORM:' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP
> [::1]:60932] Sent 26 bytes: '500 Unrecognised command\r\n' 2022/01/19
> 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Processing line:
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932]
> [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In state 1, got command
> 'UPGRADE-INSECURE-REQUESTS:', args '1' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP
> [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In ESTABLISH state 2022/01/19 11:24:04
> [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Got unknown command for
> ESTABLISH state: 'UPGRADE-INSECURE-REQUESTS:' 2022/01/19 11:24:04
> [SMTP [::1]:60932] Sent 26 bytes: '500 Unrecognised command\r\n'
> 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Processing
> line: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71
> Safari/537.36 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO:
> ESTABLISH] In state 1, got command 'USER-AGENT:', args 'Mozilla/5.0
> (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP
> [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In ESTABLISH state 2022/01/19 11:24:04
> [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Got unknown command for
> ESTABLISH state: 'USER-AGENT:' 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932]
> Sent 26 bytes: '500 Unrecognised command\r\n' 2022/01/19 11:24:04
> [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] Processing line: Accept:
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
> 2022/01/19 11:24:04 [SMTP [::1]:60932] [PROTO: ESTABLISH] In state 1,
> got command 'ACCEPT:', args

None of this says anything I can understand. How do I begin trying to figure out what's going wrong?

My dev email config is:

```
// DEV EMAIL
export const DEV_EMAIL_OPTIONS: any = {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 1025,
  secure: false,
  debug: true,
  ignoreTLS: true,
}
```